# Can't execute string to date conversion

Tags: mysql, json

Could anyone point what to read, because I'm stuck with trivial issue. I store data in JSON format and I have a key with string that consists of a non ISO format datetime value, e.g. `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S'`

I've tried function `STR_TO_DATE` on string "17-12-2019 13:49:50" and it returned SQL datetime result, but when I use it in function

```
DELETE FROM queue WHERE 
    ts = CASE 
    WHEN type = 'entry' THEN HOUR(TIMEDIFF (NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, "$.date_event"),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S'))) > 72
```

SQL raises

> Incorrect datetime value: '"07-12-2016 18:21:59"' for function
>   str_to_date

When I try statement `SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, "$.date_event"),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S')` MySQL returns `null`

Comment: I believe that the issue caused by quotes (check your error message), as simple test ```SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07-12-2016 18:21:59','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S')``` works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the double quotes returned around the extracted value. You need to either unquote the extracted value e.g.

```
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, "$.date_event"))
```

or using shorthand notation

```
request->>'$.date_event'
```

Or add the double quotes into the `STR_TO_DATE` template i.e.

```
STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(request, "$.date_event"),'"%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S"'))
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=119a7169c7ca9bb7d5f21b30a8b270d0)